# How to set object rotation as the new zero rotation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am working in Illustrator and have created a group of wedge shapes from a pie chart, which was rotated, ungrouped, and regrouped. Given that the wedges are still placed together as a circle, and that it is rotated how can I set its current orientation as the zero-rotation orientation?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `Object > Transform > Reset Bounding Box`

I'm not 100% certain what you are referring to. But this would *seem* to fit with your description.

Be aware that Illustrator does not store or remember basic object transformations. There's no way to un-rotate any object back to 0° other than doing it manually.

Comment: You can return to the reset box position by setting the transform in a script to [1 0 1 0 0 0] but you can not go back to states before that.